# SQL Script to pull duplicate data

Tags: sql, sap-iq

Need help pointing in right direction using an SQL query to extract data out of this SYBASE database example:

```
12345  blue
12345  red
12345  green
56789  purple
56789  black
98765  brown

output must look like this:
12345 blue red green
56789 purple black
98765 brown
```

Was trying to use "union" or maybe "distinct"
Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle uses WM_CONCAT or LIST_AGG to do this anymore I think sysbase uses List()

[Source documentation describing function](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/list-function.html)

So.. using your SQL

```
Select Field1, list(Field2)
FROM table
Group by Field1


SELECT item_loc.niin, list(item_loc.location_number)
FROM item_loc 
GROUP BY item_loc.niin
```

I just removed a space after list before the ( so `List (` became `List(`

Now the nature of the error your getting indicates list isn't a function in your version of sybase... I'm still trying to find documentation on sybase 15.3 and proper syntax for it (or if it supports List)

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. It says function "list" not found. Using SYBASE 15.3. Here is my query:

Comment: here is my query:                                                  SELECT 
   item_loc.niin,
   list (item_loc.location_number)   
FROM 
   item_loc
group by item_loc.niin

Comment: So I guess this is inaccurate: http://ongundemirler.blogspot.com/2012/04/sybase-iq-equavalent-for-oracle.html

Comment: @xQbert Sybase IQ != Sybase ASE