# How to combine resulting rows into a single row seperated by commas

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I've been trying to combine my query results into a single row with each set of tag and associatedid values separated by a comma.

Using the following values:

```
tag         associatedid
MA2D8111AM  MA2D811S
MA2D8112AM  MA2D811S
MA2D8113AM  MA2D811S
MA2D8114AM  MA2D811S
MA2D8115AM  MA2D811S
MA2D8116AM  MA2D811S
MA2D8117AM  MA2D811S
MA2D8118AM  MA2D811S
MA2D8119AM  MA2D811S
```

I would like to select these set of values in such a way that they would be displayed as followed:

MA2D8111AM:MA2D811S,MA2D8112AM:MA2D811S,MA2D8113AM:MA2D811S,MA2D8114AM:MA2D811S,MA2D8115AM:MA2D811S,MA2D8116AM:MA2D811S,MA2D8117AM:MA2D811S,MA2D8118AM:MA2D811S,MA2D8119AM:MA2D811S

I have managed to combine the two columns with ":" using the following, but honestly have no idea how to combine all the set of tags and associatedid on the same row:

```
SELECT tag+":"+associatedid FROM tagidtable
```

When reading through sql_server examples, I have not been able to replicate user's successes when applying COALESCE in sybase. Any tips or feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of sybase?  Does it support the "LIST" Function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094656/sql-script-to-pull-duplicate-data http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/list-function.html

Comment: Concatenating strings from rows into a single string is not an easy thing to do in SQL.  You usually have to write some sort of function that loops through the results with a cursor.  Would it be possible to do it in the application/reporting layer instead?

Comment: Not easy?  For XML(SQL_SERVER), WM_CONCAT (ORACLE < 10g), LIST_AGG (ORACLE), Group_Concat(MySQL), LIST (SQLAnywhere-Sybase) seems easy to me... but if it's not one of these RDBMS we just need to find the similar function and if not then build...

Comment: sorry, we are using ase 15.7

Comment: "Function 'LIST' not found." Doesn't look good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with what's available in sybase but I assume you can do some sort of while loop. This should get you started, I would convert this into a function to be reusable. I didn't put this in a cursor which would just allow you to fetch next, instead I just put 1,2,3,4 but I just wanted to illustrate the idea without providing the exact code :-)

```
CREATE TABLE ConvertRowsToSingleCell
(
    sequence int
    ,tag varchar(max)
    ,associatedId varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO ConvertRowsToSingleCell
VALUES 
    (1,'MA2D8111AM', 'MA2D811S')
    ,(2, 'MA2D8112AM', 'MA2D811S')
    ,(3, 'MA2D8113AM', 'MA2D811S')
    ,(4, 'MA2D8114AM', 'MA2D811S')

DECLARE @Length int = (Select COUNT(*) FROM ConvertRowsToSingleCell)
        ,@Increment int = 1
        ,@Item varchar(max)
        ,@ConcatenatedString varchar(max);

WHILE @Increment <= @Length
BEGIN

    IF (@Increment = @Length) --Remove comma at end
        BEGIN
            Select @Item = tag + ':' + associatedId from ConvertRowsToSingleCell
            where @Increment = sequence
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            Select @Item = tag + ':' + associatedId + ', ' from ConvertRowsToSingleCell
            where @Increment = sequence
        END
    Set @ConcatenatedString = ISNULL(@ConcatenatedString,'') + @Item
    SET @Increment = @Increment + 1 
END

Select @ConcatenatedString
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to work on a modern version of SQL server, but I have my doubts as to whether sybase has the same syntax and functionality around "FOR XML"

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT  ', ' + RTRIM(tag+':'+associatedid) [text()]
     FROM tagidtable  
     FOR XML PATH('') 
    ), 2, 1000000000)
```

Comment: Unfortunately XML cannot be read on our version of sybase, it's one of those sad moments when there are thousands of solutions...but for another sql version